# Jquery TimePicker How do I change the Title that says Hours or Minutes to something else?

Tags: jquery

How do I change the Title that says Hour to something else?

```
$('#from').timepicker({
    hourLabel:"ChangeMyName", <-----
    showPeriodLabels: false,
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss 
});
```

This does not seem to work!

Comment: Maybe refresh browser cache, then reload to double check?

Comment: Can you specify which plugin you are using?  Bootstrap 3/4? jquery-ui?

Comment: For some reason I tried hourText instead and it worked.. it was 0.3.3